# How to post json to server Unity WWW WWW string has invalid arguments

Tags: c#, json, curl, unity-game-engine

I am looking to post this json to server and get some json in return. I don't know what I am missing but I have a compiler error the best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.WWW.WWW(string)` has some invalid arguments

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
public class Post_Server_Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SendJson());
    }
    IEnumerator SendJson()
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
        form.AddField("offer_message", "Hello world");
        form.AddField("offer_name", "Great Deals");
        form.AddField("start", "20171015 103025 UTC");
        form.AddField("end", "20171015 103025 UTC");
        form.AddField("type", "self");
        form.AddField("value", "transport");
        form.AddField("amount", "1.00");
        yield return "start";

        WWW w = new WWW (form);
        yield return w;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(w.error))
        {
            print(w.error);
        }
        else
        {
            print("json sent to server");
        }
    }

    public void OnConnectedToServer()
    {
        Debug.Log("Im connected");
    }
}
```

Comment: Obvious error, passing WWWForm  to a method which is expecting string, Did you even try to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an instance of the type `WWWForm` here:

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
```

Then you are providing that object as argument to the constructor of `WWW` here:

```
WWW w = new WWW (form);
```

That constructor's signature accepts a string argument.  This has nothing to do with json, curl, or even the WWW class.  It's a type mismatch.

Comment: What kind of string can you be more specific?

Comment: I can't, actually, because I'm simply quoting the compiler's warning to you: `the best overloaded method match for UnityEngine.WWW.WWW(string) has some invalid arguments` which should be clear.  I've explained that you're passing an _object_ and the method, according to your own report of the compiler error, is expecting a _string_

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the URL in to the `WWW` object's constuctor, the form is the second parameter.

```
WWW w = new WWW ("http://example.com/scores", form);
```